# stretch image to fit div using jquery css method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook

This is the generated html

```
<div id="largephoto" style="background-image: url(http://somepath/images/sample.jpg);">
```

and here is my js call

```
$('#loader').css('background-image','url("images/sample/gif" )');
```

I want the image to be like in facebook, regard too small or too large the user uploaded photo, the frame should show the center of the photo and leave no white space within the frame.

I tried       `$('#largephoto').css('background-image-position','center');`
but it seem do nothing

Comment: why not use width height 100%?

Answer (score 1):

Use css `background-size` property for fixing the image in DIV

```
$('#largephoto').css('background-size','100%,100%');
```

Comment: no, this will not make it fill the frame fully, it left white space if the img is smaller than the frame. look at facebook feed example, no white space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS :-

```
.img_class {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will adjust image sucha a way that image will be cover its container.

```
#largephoto {
    background-size:cover;
}
```